# Just uploaded laravel app on live server but it's not loading

Tags: laravel

I just uploaded a laravel application to a live server. At first it loaded on desktop but after visiting on mobile, it gave this response:

```
    Header shows: localhost/

    This site can’t be reached
    localhost is currently unreachable.
    ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Error on desktop after visiting again

```
    This page isn’t working
    mysite.com sent an invalid response.
    ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: check the env if as APP_URL there is the website url, clear the cache (php artisan cache:clear) and delete all the logs

Comment: I have typed in the website url in the APP_URL. Does it have to remain as localhost or the actual website url? Also should the the APP_ENV remain local or changed to production?

Comment: The app_env must be or local or staging, and so you should leave to local, but the app url have to be the url of your website (it's used like to generate the url in the url() helper function, and may cause issue if not set correctly)

Comment: Thanks. What about the APP_KEY? Do I have to use only the string or everything after the "=" sign? Plus how do I delete all the logs coz I've already uploaded everything?

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. **`This page isn’t working
    mysite.com sent an invalid response.
    ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`**   .Please help me out.

Comment: Hey cd4success! Anything in your logs on the live server?

Comment: Also, how did you upload the application? Git? Where is the site hosted - azure / aws, etc?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane, I do have two files of the same name in live server logs(mysite.com-Dec-2019.gz) and (mysite.com-ssl_log-Dec-2019.gz). I uploaded it via SFTP and hosted on Namecheap shared hosting. Please help me!

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of those logs? This screams DNS issue to me. Have you looked through Namecheaps [getting started](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/subcategory.aspx/27/getting-started) tutorials?

Comment: The output of the logs is unreadable to me. I have gone through Namecheap's tutorials. There is a folder inside my Public_folder named **`C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\storage\logs`**  and inside this folder is a filed named **`laravel-2019-12-21.log`**. I don't know how it got there coz I didn't upload it. Actually, the website loaded initially but when I tried it on mobile, it says **localhost is unreachable**, then I tried it on desktop and it started giving **invalid response**.